# Process Monitor(Procmon) on Windows Server

Tags: windows, files

I am having issue in one specific file which is used by Operating system and it seems to be locked and doesn't give  access to my database. Since file is inaccessible by database, query/job/application everything starts failing as the underlying file is the log for system database tempdb. You may refer my [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/235330/log-for-database-tempdb-is-not-available) at another forum in the same umbrella. Below is the error description which gets reported in Windows log:

> SQLServerLogMgr::LogWriter: Operating system error 170(The requested
>   resource is in use.) encountered.

I have been told that if I use sysinternals or procmon, I would be able to track which program is actually using it. This is because my OS and storage admin is not accepting that this file is used by any program or operating system. They are also saying that this type of file is excluded from anti-virus scan however I need to see the proof of the same.

I tried running procmon in my local system and included one specific path so that I could track access to files stored there by any program however couldn't get anything.

[image: Include Filter]

Unless I get comfortable with this monitoring tool and feel that this would be suitable for my requirement, can't think of putting on the server.

> Server Version: Windows Server 2012 Standard

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's pretty weird; if the problem were that another program had the file open, you'd get error 5 (access denied) or error 32 (sharing violation).  Some quick research suggests that error 170 might instead be caused by problems with the disk volume, e.g., if it is a volume on a SAN which is temporarily unavailable because it is being snapshotted, backed up, or due to hardware issues.

Comment: As a side note: it's better to use `Process Explorer` to see which process is currently locking the file. In general `Process Monitor` will not show you the file that was already locked.

Comment: @montonero Could you please add a bit more details on process explorer and how to find out the process which is holding my db file.

Comment: Sure. Run `Process Explorer` with elevated privileges, then press `Ctrl-F` and search for a file name (or any part of its path). It will find all opened handles of this file.

Comment: @montonero I was thinking its a part of Operating System, after searching on net, I came to know this is another sysinternal. I downloaded the same and was looking for my file through Ctrl-F however couldn't do. I have open the file in SSMS(Sql Server Management Studio). I guess, it supports only DLL or EXE in search and not file name. Could you please guide me.

Comment: It supports any opened handles, not only exe or dll, but even registry keys. If Process Explorer can't find the handle there could be two reasons: the file handle is currently not exists or Process Explorer isn't run with enough privileges. Some applications don't hold a handle of a file: they read its content to a memory and then close the handle (from the user's perspective the file is still opened). I. e. compare MS Word and Notepad.

Comment: Process Monitor might very well give you some clues as to what is going on *if it is capturing data at the time the incident occurs*.  I'd suggest running it without any filters and then looking for activity around the time of the incident.  You should at the very least be able to see the failed request from SQL Server.